# Can't open downloaded file

Tags: android, ftp, download

I tried download apk file from ftp, but i can't open that file after download.
Original file and downloaded file have same size.
Im using apache commons.
My code:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try{
            ftpClient.connect(mServer);        
            ftpClient.login(mUser, mPassword);              ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            BufferedOutputStream FileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cestaLuHa),8*1024);
            boolean status=ftpClient.retrieveFile("LuHa.apk", desFileStream);
            if(status){
                result = "Downlaoded";
            }
            FileStream.flush();
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            result = "Error";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download file;

```
FTPClient client = null;
File ExternalDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File DownloadFile = new File(ExternalDirectory.getAbsoluteFile()+"//"+"file.apk");
    try {
        client = new FTPClient();
        client.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
        client.connect(mServer, 21);
        client.login(mUser,mPassword);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DownloadFile));
        boolean success = client.retrieveFile("//httpdocs//file.apk", outputStream);
        if (!success) {
            outputStream.close();
            Log.v("Download Status","Not Download");
        } else {
            outputStream.close();
            Log.v("Download Status","Downloaded");
        }
```

This is the second part for open apk;

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(DownloadFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/apk"); //Maybe it 's different check different website for this
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Last thing i must to say ,you have to do this in background ,after 3.0 android blocked in foreground download , you should use AsyncTask for this .
Hope this will be help for you

Comment: Both parts work perfectly. Thank you. Problem seemed to be in saving downloaded file in to internal storage.